# notifyDataSetChanged does not update the listView of custom objects after sorting

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am trying to sort the collection in custom arrayadapter and making a call to update the view . However, the view does not gets updated.

There are two values over which I want to sort (date and amount) and have a custom comparators for them.

I can see that the data itself has changed (i.e if a list item has gone outside of view after sorting and when it gets the view, the data it show is the correct data that should exist after sorting).

The second question is about the filter. The way the filter is implemented right now, it does not update the views either.

Here is code

```
public class SearchActivity extends BListActivity {

private Bundle sessionInfo;
private TransactionDetailsHandler transactionDetailsHandler = new TransactionDetailsHandler();
private static boolean ascDate = false;
private static boolean ascAmount = false;

private ArrayList<TransactionDetails> transactionDetails;
private ArrayList<TransactionDetails> filterResults;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sessionInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String sessionId = sessionInfo.getString("sessionId");
    final String transactionResponse = sessionInfo
            .getString(C.TRN_DETAIL_KEY);

    try {
        Xml.parse(transactionResponse, transactionDetailsHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<TransactionDetails> adapter = getArrayAdapter();

    findViewById(R.id.amount_btn).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (ascDate) {
                        adapter.sort(new TransactionDetailAmountComparatorAsc());
                        ascDate = false;
                    } else {
                        adapter.sort(new TransactionDetailAmountComparatorDesc());
                        ascDate = true;
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

    findViewById(R.id.date_btn).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (ascAmount) {
                        adapter.sort(new TransactionDetailDateComparatorAsc());
                        ascAmount = false;
                    } else {
                        adapter.sort(new TransactionDetailDateComparatorDesc());
                        ascAmount = true;
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

    findViewById(R.id.search_btn).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    findViewById(R.id.buttonLL).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.searchLL).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

    findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    findViewById(R.id.searchLL).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.buttonLL).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

    TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            System.out.println("XXXX Constraint = " + s);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    };

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_box);
    et.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

}

protected ArrayAdapter<TransactionDetails> getArrayAdapter() {
    transactionDetails = transactionDetailsHandler
            .getTransactionDetailsList();
    filterResults = transactionDetails;
    return new SearchListAdapter(this,
            (List<TransactionDetails>) transactionDetails);
}

protected class SearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TransactionDetails> {
    private int rId;
    private List<TransactionDetails> data;
    private Filter filter;

    public SearchListAdapter(Context context, List<TransactionDetails> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.search_list_item, data);
        this.rId = R.layout.search_list_item;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View cv, ViewGroup parent) {
        cv = getLayoutInflater().inflate(rId, parent, false);
        TransactionDetails item = data.get(position);

        ((TextView) cv.findViewById(R.id.t_id)).setText(item.getTrnId());
        ((TextView) cv.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(item
                .getTrnDatetime());
        ((TextView) cv.findViewById(R.id.amount)).setText(item
                .getTrnAmount());
        ((TextView) cv.findViewById(R.id.card_num))
                .setText("XXXX XXXX XXXX " + item.getTrnMaskedCard());

        try {
            if (item.getTrnCardType() != null
                    && item.getTrnCardType().trim().length() > 0)
                ((ImageView) cv.findViewById(R.id.card_img))
                        .setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(item
                                .getTrnCardType()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        ((TextView) cv.findViewById(R.id.result)).setText(item
                .getTrnStatus());
        return cv;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new TransactionDetailFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    private class TransactionDetailFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            System.out.println("XXXX Started filtering with Constraint = "
                    + constraint);
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                ArrayList<TransactionDetails> list = new ArrayList<TransactionDetails>(
                        transactionDetails);
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();
            } else {
                final ArrayList<TransactionDetails> list = new ArrayList<TransactionDetails>(
                        transactionDetails);
                final ArrayList<TransactionDetails> nlist = new ArrayList<TransactionDetails>();
                int count = list.size();
                System.out
                        .println("XXXX List to be search size = " + count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final TransactionDetails details = list.get(i);
                    System.out.println("XXXX List to be searched = "
                            + details.toString());
                    if (details.getTrnId().startsWith(prefix)
                            || details.getTrnDatetime().startsWith(prefix)
                            || details.getTrnAmount().startsWith(prefix)
                            || details.getTrnMaskedCard()
                                    .startsWith(prefix)
                            || details.getTrnStatus().startsWith(prefix)) {
                        System.out.println("XXXX Adding result "
                                + details.toString());
                        nlist.add(details);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
            }
            System.out.println("XXXX Ended filtering with Constraint = "
                    + constraint + " . Result size = " + results.count);
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            System.out.println("XXXX Preparing to publish results. Result size = "+ results.count);
            ArrayList<TransactionDetails> fitems = (ArrayList<TransactionDetails>) results.values;

            clear();
            int count = fitems.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                TransactionDetails details = (TransactionDetails) fitems
                        .get(i);
                add(details);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("XXXX Finished publishing results.");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void add(TransactionDetails item) {
        System.out.println("XXXX Adding items to be published." + item.toString());
        filterResults.add(item);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TransactionDetailAmountComparatorAsc implements
        Comparator<TransactionDetails> {
    public int compare(TransactionDetails detail1,
            TransactionDetails detail2) {
        float f = Float.parseFloat(detail1.getTrnAmount())
                - Float.parseFloat(detail2.getTrnAmount());
        if (f > 0)
            return 1;
        if (f < 1)
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
}

class TransactionDetailAmountComparatorDesc implements
        Comparator<TransactionDetails> {
    public int compare(TransactionDetails detail1,
            TransactionDetails detail2) {
        float f = Float.parseFloat(detail1.getTrnAmount())
                - Float.parseFloat(detail2.getTrnAmount());
        if (f > 0)
            return -1;
        if (f < 1)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}

class TransactionDetailDateComparatorAsc implements
        Comparator<TransactionDetails> {
    public int compare(TransactionDetails detail1,
            TransactionDetails detail2) {
        detail1.getTrnDatetime();
        detail2.getTrnDatetime();
        String pattern = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            Date date1 = format.parse(detail1.getTrnDatetime());
            Date date2 = format.parse(detail2.getTrnDatetime());
            return date1.compareTo(date2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

class TransactionDetailDateComparatorDesc implements
        Comparator<TransactionDetails> {
    public int compare(TransactionDetails detail1,
            TransactionDetails detail2) {
        detail1.getTrnDatetime();
        detail2.getTrnDatetime();
        String pattern = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            Date date1 = format.parse(detail1.getTrnDatetime());
            Date date2 = format.parse(detail2.getTrnDatetime());
            return -(date1.compareTo(date2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    position -= ((ListView) parent).getHeaderViewsCount();
    TransactionDetails details = (TransactionDetails) parent.getAdapter()
            .getItem(position);

    Bundle b = new Bundle(sessionInfo);
    b.putSerializable(C.TRN_DETAIL_KEY, details);
    Util.openView(SearchActivity.this, TransDetailActivity.class, b);
}

@Override
protected int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.search_layout;
}

@Override
protected int getStringArrayID() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getDestinations() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected int getTitleId() {
    return R.string.search;
}
```

}